# MvcSitemapProvider is returning all in Https instead of Http

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

i am using MvcSitemapProvider and is working fine, but
its returning all results in Https instead of Http.

i am unable to find a way to return the results in http (sitemap for search engine)

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="Home" action="News" dynamicNodeProvider="DynamicPostDetailsProvider, MyNamespace" updatePriority="Normal" />
```

returns like

```
<url>
    <loc>https://localhost:1118/Home</loc>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    <priority>0.75</priority>
   </url>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this workitem](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/workitem/4712) is of interest to you. This bug was fixed after the 2.0.0 release was published, so you may need to check out latest source and build it yourself.